# Reload root view controller after child view controller dismiss

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this structure:

Root View controller -> View Controller (Language choose) Presented by modal segue.

Is it possible using delegates, to reload root view controller, to present it with new chosen language values. I use runtime language selection by localize.strings entries. The issue is that despite after language change, child languages are shown in new language, but root view is still with the old one.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the delegate or block, you have to load the localised nib, and get the strings right from it. `NSLocalizedString` will load the preferred language from the user defaults, and then the changes will only take effect after restarting the app. That's why you have manually load the appropriate lproj by yourself.

You can take a look at a demo app [here](https://github.com/volonbolon/localizedVC)

Answer (score 1):

Yes use a delegate method or a block. When either one is triggered in the rootViewController dismiss the child view and make your changes.

Comment: Mnay thanks. But, how I can make the root view controller to reload again with new localized values for its components?